# Why does reviewing edits require three people, but making edits requires only yourself (after 2k reputation points)?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-tags

According to [the privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) we can make instant edits when we hit 2k reputation points. However, reviewing other peoples edits still requires some consensus between users.

This makes no sense to me. In theory, I could just make the suggested edit myself and bypass the consensus. So why do we still mandate multiple reviewers for suggested edits? This seems to send contradicting messages: "You can do it yourself, but you can't judge other people yourself."